# How can I implement something like OnFieldAccessAspect of PostSharp?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I was reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1853790/196210 and I wanted to use PostSharp in my project but when I started reading their license I got really disappointed.

Is there any other way to implement logging when accessing a property?

http://www.postsharp.net/purchase/faq

> How is the concurrent license enforced?
>
> PostSharp periodically uploads usage data to our servers and these are
> analyzed for license compliance.
>
> Is it possible to get a PostSharp Express company license for our
> whole team?
>
> No. Unlike the commercial editions of PostSharp, free PostSharp
> Express licenses are named-user licenses and thus require every
> developer to check out their own license. If you need company
> licensing, choose PostSharp Professional or PostSharp Ultimate
> edition.

Comment: Note that license audit can be disabled on demand for commercial PostSharp licenses. However license auditing is a more customer-friendly way to enforce license than what all vendors are doing.

Comment: @GaelFraiteur: yes.. for me it become really hard to try this software (for free at work time). I think you can start "boring" people if you already have a very solid base. It will be very hard to grow if you don't allow developers to try. They have a base version. Stop. Leave people to use it. Want people to pay? Ok.. give them more features, but don't annoy them with strange licences.. In my opinion for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) for weaving your logging policy directly into the syntax tree, in compile time. One way to do it is to automatically generate `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementations for your properties. This could be done by traversing the syntax trees looking for property nodes and modifying them, including RaisePropertyChanged calls accordingly. It's a fair amount of work, but in the end you would have a modular and extensible logging aspect. I found [this post](http://www.clickpointsoftware.com/blog/index.php/2011/12/20/dynamic-code-generation-and-analysis-using-microsoft-roslyn-ctp/) on how to dynamically generate code using Roslyn, but the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) is also fairly helpful.