# A method that fires when a class or its properties are accessed

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, reflection

I have an issue on my project that only happens once in a while, and hence difficult to trace:

> Nullable object must have a value.
>   Blockquote

So I want to implement a way to log all attempts on accessing a class / class property that is not defined. basically a method that executes every time a class or its properties are accessed.

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853727/a-method-that-executes-any-time-a-class-property-is-accessed-get-or-set), but I think my requirements are different. 
And I would appreciate any suggestions that don't include third party plugins.

Any ideas?

**What I have done:** an object extension method

```
public static T LogMyClass<T>(this T myClass)
{
   if (myClass == null) 
     //code to log this class

   return myClass;
}
```

but obviously this is not feasible, as it requires to be add onto every object that I what to log in the project

**Edit 1**
Ok, the ***Custom Attribute*** option suggested by @kienct89 can work, but only for class properties. If the class is `null` it won't reach / fire the property attribute.

Any further ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: one convenient way is implement a custom `Attribute`, so you can decorate on any property that you need to **watch**. This might be a good start: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13353/Using-Attributes-and-RealProxy-to-perform-property

Comment: Do yo have only one instance of that class? Like Singleton?

Comment: @kienct89, thank you, That article looks interesting maybe what I am looking for. I will give it a try and let you know later on if it works.

Comment: @fafase no, may be multiple instances, not a singleton

Comment: why you say PostSharp isn't enough to solve your issue?

Comment: I've closed it anyway pointing to the question you already pointed out. There's no built-in way to achieve your goal without using "plugins" (or call them "frameworks").